# Why is this sort ~3000X slower than list.sort()?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm new to python and was building a sorter "just for fun". I got curious and decided to time it and compare it to list.sort(). Well for a randomized list of 10,000 numbers my program takes 50-70 seconds. list.sort() takes 0.015 seconds. Searching only brings up results for list.sort() vs sorted How is list.sort() so much more efficient? 
This is the program:

```
import time
import random
ct=0
while ct<5:
    List=[]
    count =0 
    while count< 10000:#builds a random list
        List.append(random.randint(0,100))
        count = count + 1
        #print List
    n=0
    c=0
    T1=time.clock()
    while c<len(List):#sorts said list
        n=0
        for i in List:
            if i > List[c]:
                #print ('%d %s %d'%(List[c],'was inserted at',n))
            List.insert(n,List.pop(c))
            n=n+1  
        c=c+1
#print List
print time.clock()-T1
ct=ct+1
```

Comment: You have indentation mistakes in your code.

Comment: Is there a better way to insert code? I c&p it and then had to re-indent everything with the spacebar, tab was a no go.

Comment: Your sort is O(N^3) in the worst (and average) case.

Comment: @NickSachs: after pasting, select your code and press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 2):

1. `list.sort` is implemented in C, expect slowdowns of 1-2 orders of magnitude just for the fact of rewriting the same algorithm in Python.
2. `list.insert` is O(n) and it's in a twice nested loop over the list elements; so your algorithm looks like O(n^3) in the average case, while any self-respecting sort algorithm is O(n log n).
3. Even in the realm of O(n log n) algorithms, Python's one ([Timsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) has significant speedup tricks that expedite the sorting on real-world datasets (and avoids some degenerations of "naive" quicksort).

Comment: @Holt: Python lists are actually arrays, insertion in the middle requires moving forward of one step all the elements that follow.